# Problem with height in video shortcode

Tags: shortcode

i think there is a problem with the video shortcode.

When i use `[video src="" height="400"]` the **400px** height not work. The width work correctly but the height nothing.

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seems to be a bug, but it's designed like that only...

Have a look how height variable is being changed by other parameter to keep up the right video ratio based on the theme.

```
if ( 'video' === $type ) {
             $width = empty( $meta['width'] ) ? 640 : $meta['width'];
             $height = empty( $meta['height'] ) ? 360 : $meta['height'];
             $theme_height = round( ( $height * $theme_width ) / $width );
             $track['dimensions'] = array(
                     'original' => compact( 'width', 'height' ),
                     'resized' => array(
                             'width' => $theme_width,
                             'height' => $theme_height
                     )
             );
 }
```

Reference: [Codex](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/media.php#L1007) : Line No. 1092